# getting string from preferences

Tags: android, preferences

So I have `EditTextPreference` in my `Preferences`, I want to type something in and save it, then i want to get that text in `Activity`. My key of `EditTextPreference` is B1. I tried this code :

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
               String samples = getPrefs.getString("B1", "");
               b1.setText(samples);
```

---

```
<EditTextPreference
            android:dialogTitle="Button 1"
            android:key="B1"
            android:summary="Set text on button 1"
            android:title="Set text on button 1" />
```

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` between those

```
String samples = getPrefs.getString("B1", "lol");
            b1.setText(samples);
```

Comment: what's the current issue??

Comment: java lang nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

***Home.java***

```
public class Home extends Activity {

public SharedPreferences prefs;

String mValues;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     mValues= prefs.getString("male", "female");
}
```

}

***Preferences.java***

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity  implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPref, String key) {
        Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("B1")){
            editor.putString("male","my value"); 
        }

        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: 03-01 18:47:40.136: E/AndroidRuntime(3196): java.lang.NullPointerException
at 345 row which is String samples = getPrefs.getString("B1", "lol");

Answer (score 2):

Declare:

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Put a value (can be int, String, etc)

```
 String tom = "tom";
    pref.edit().putString("tom", tom).commit(); // To set a value to SharedPreferences
```

Get a value (remember the type)

```
String name = pref.getString("tom", null); // To get a value from SharedPreferences
```

See [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 1):

In order to write to SharedPreferences you can use:

```
   Editor editor = getPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("B1", "you value here");
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: i dont wanna write to preferences, i wanna getstring from preferences